# How to code all for all cases of Two Sum javascript problem

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have been working on the two sum problem for the past few hours and can't seem to account for the case where there are only two numbers and their sum is the same as the first number doubled.

The result should be [0,1], but i'm getting [0,0].

```js
let nums = [3,3];
let targetNum = 6;

function twoSum(nums, target) {

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (let b = i+1; b < nums.length; b++) {
            if ((nums[i] + nums[b]) == target) {
                return [nums.indexOf(nums[i]), nums.indexOf(nums[b])];
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(twoSum(nums, targetNum))
```

Comment: Why use `nums.indexOf(nums[i])` and `nums.indexOf(nums[b])` instead of simply `i` and `b`?

Comment: `return [i, b];`. But for this problem O(n^2) complexity is a waste. Use hashmap to achieve linear time complexity.

Comment: @Bergi—because if the number is repeated in the array, `nums.indexOf(nums[i])` may not be equal to `i` and mysterious bugs would not occur!! :-)

Comment: Review your code sure you can use one bucle "for".

Comment: `nums.indexOf(nums[i])` always returns the index of the first match, so in `[3,3]` where `nums[i] == 3` then `indexOf(nums[i])` will always return 0, even when `i` is 1.

Comment: I wish people actually gave these as answers.

Answer (score 1):

## Two Sum

My approach uses a javascript object and completes the algorithm in **O(n)** time complexity.

```
const twoSum = (nums, target) => {
  let hash = {}
  for(i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
    if (hash[nums[i]]!==undefined) {
      return [hash[nums[i]], i];
    }
    hash[target-nums[i]] = i;
  }
};

console.log(twoSum([2,7,11,15], 9)); // example
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to solve the problem. Step through the array and save the complement of the target wrt the number in the array. This will also solve your corner case.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider, indexOf(i) -> start from the first element, returns the index when match found! That is why in your code, *nums.indexOf(nums[i])* and *nums.indexOf(nums[b])* which is basically 3 in all two cases, it will return 0, cause 3 is the first element in array.

instead of doing this, return the index itself.

```
let nums = [3,3];
let targetNum = 6;

function twoSum(nums, target) {

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (let b = i+1; b < nums.length; b++) {
            if ((nums[i] + nums[b]) == target) {
                return i + "" +b;
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(twoSum(nums, targetNum))
```